# Careers - overall statistics

Tags: feature-request, jobs, statistics

So I can see some careers statistics that are site wide:

- How many employers
- How many searches

What I'm most interested in, though, are site-wide statistics surrounding success rate.

- How many searches resulted in mailing one or more requests for interviews
- How many interviews resulted in job offers
- How many job offers accepted
- Percentage of CVs that received at least one interview request each year compared to number of CVs in the system

This requires more follow up, and I'm wondering if Careers has a 'tracking' system to follow up on email and interview requests so that this data can be gathered, and whether those statistics will be displayed.

If it doesn't already exist, I'd like it added as a feature.  This will be useful for everyone considering paying the full price (or resubscribing after their beta price ends).

Answer (score 1):

I am not really interested in site-wide statistics. It seems like they would only be a tool for criticizing the effectiveness of the site. If the site is successful in getting people employed, I am sure we will hear about it... all over the blog, Joel's site, CodingHorror.com several podcasts, FogCreek notepads, CodingHorror stickers, and a brand new StackOverflow CareerDays® tour.

What I am interested in is seeing what employer search queries are. For example, if an employer is searching for San Francisco, and I have San Jose listed, I wouldn't mind adding that location to my profile. Or if they are searching asp.net instead of C#, etc. The point is I'm not sure what I'm missing because theirs no visibility on what employers are searching for.

Anyway, I am happy overall with the site so far.

Answer (score 1):

Careers is a great idea, as long as it works. I'm concerned that there are still only 12 employers listed. I presume they are all in the North Eastern portion of the US. **Would be nice to click on to see if there are any employers signing on from my general area (Orange County, CA).** If not, I may not renew after the beta period. Of course, since my goal is a New-Job-By-Spring, this may be a moot point.